# Car idles a little funny

Tags: rough-idle, infiniti

I haven’t used my car in about 4 days because I was out of town for the holidays. I just got back and when I started my car it started fine but my idle went down to 200-300 RPM, then RPMs went back to normal 900 RPM. I warmed up the car then drove it. Nothing happened and everything drove perfectly. I started the car again after 10 minutes without using after the drive and ran up perfectly. Should I be concerned? Is it an early sign of an issue? Car is a 1991 Infiniti m30

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it ran perfect after it was run for a bit, then started and runs fine every time after, I'd suggest there's nothing to worry about. Cars, just like people, get cold and crotchety when they aren't run every so often. The old girl was just letting you know you hadn't started her in a few days. Really, there should be nothing to worry about. If there was a check engine light and continued to run bad, then I might be worried about it.